# how can I point two different domains to one directory in apache centos 7

Tags: server, centos

I have Two domains xyz.com and xyz.in. I need to point these two domains one directory. I have two different SSL certificates also. Can I do this ?

Comment: you will have 2 diffrent certificates in one directory and in your apache configuration, you should add certificate and key file name.

Answer (score 1):

you will have 2 diffrent certificates in one directory and in your apache configuration, you should add certificate and key file name.